# How to remove anchor tag around rescaled images in readthedocs site?

Tags: html, css, image, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I use an alias without any width or height modifiers to display an image:

```
.. |downloads_png| image:: assets/index/downloads_v2.png
```

This image is rendered correctly, without any decoration.

I add a height modifier to resize this image:

```
.. |downloads_png| image:: assets/index/downloads_v2.png
                   :height: 26px
```

When I do this, my readthedocs page shows this image with a grey line underneath:

[image: downloads image with grey bar underneath]

What is happening is that an anchor tag is (for whatever reason) being wrapped around the `img` tag for this image, and the anchor tag has a text decoration style applied to it, which adds the grey underlining.

How do I prevent this from happening? I do not need to download the image when mousing over it. I just want to display the image.

Comment: try `text-decoration:none;`

Comment: Is this added to the alias?

Comment: don't know anything about readthedocs, but try this`|downloads_png| image:: assets/index/downloads_v2.png,
                   :height: 26px,:text-decoration:none` Don't know if it will work but in css that's the kiddie to get rid of the underline.Is there supposed to be a comma or semi colon after assets/index/downloads_v2.png ? Seems strange that you have nothing seperating the values

Comment: Nope, that's not going to work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. worth a shot...